# Why is my create.js.erb not rendering?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a comment page where the comment is submitted with AJAX, I'm using Rails 3 and in my form_for block I'm setting :remote => true. Looking at the Chrome developer tool I can see that the server is returning the page create.js.erb as text/javascript, but the javascript is not being executed.

commentable_controller

```
def create
  @commentable = Commentable.new
  @commentable.body = params[:body]
  @commentable.user = current_user
  if @commentable.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
    alert("hello world");
```

show.html.haml

```
    #feed
      =render :partial => "commentable/commentable", :collection => @commentables
    -form_tag('/commentable/create', :remote => true) do
      =hidden_field_tag :game_id, @game.id
      =text_area_tag :body, nil, :rows => 3, :value => "160 Characters", :id => 'new_message'
      =submit_tag "Post"
```

Edits:

After looking into this more, I can see that the request is going in as HTML which is not correct. Apparently this has something to do with the prototype version that Rails 3 is using... wtf rails

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that maybe jquery-mobile is somehow interfering with the javascript on create.js.erb

Comment: can you show the view with :remote => true ?

Comment: i am not sure about rails 3 but in previous versions of rails javascript does not load when a ajax request is processed... you have write code to include java script manually.....

Answer (score 0):

Did you install jquery correctly for rails3? E.g. using the [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) gem it is really simple. Just add the gem to your `Gemfile` and type

```
rails g jquery:install
```

Then what you did should just work.